# Suppress ouput of a method

Tags: python, linux

I have a python method that reads some files and perform some actions on the data written in them. And it prints to stdout something like this:

```
Reading somefile
Reading somefile2
.
.
.
```

Would it be possible to suppress this output without changing the source code ? either with bash or a python tool ?

Comment: `myprog.py > /dev/null` ...

Comment: Maybe something like `>/dev/null 2>&1` ?

Comment: I actually use this method in a script and i would like to keep the output of other methods within this script

Comment: try `myprog.py | grep -v "^Reading "`

Comment: Works ! thanks . Guess i need to learn everything that grep can do !